# What heirloom weapons should a DPS death knight pick up

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Exactly as the title states, I am interested in leveling a DPS death knight and wanted to get heirloom for him. I picked up shoulders/chest. Assuming I'll go for a DPS spec, what weapon(s) (if it isn't one 2H weapon?) should I pick up for heirloom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really aren't too many options.

For a dual-wielding DPS DK, you can either dual-wield two [Venerable Mass of McGowan](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48716), or wield it in your off-hand and [Venerable Dal'Rend's Sacred Charge](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42945) in your main hand. As of Patch 4.3, it's really only viable for frost DKs to dual-wield. Since the haste stat is slightly more valuable than crit (as haste decreases weapon speed meaning more [killing machine](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=51128) proc as well as the rune refresh speed), it's probably more advisable for you to go for the first option when dual-wielding. Neither weapon provides any strength unfortunately.

For a 2H DPS DK, the only option is [Bloodied Arcanite Reaper](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42943). You can probably use it up to level 80, or more if you don't get a better weapon by then.